# Have two forms in one page and set session

Tags: php, forms, session

i have two file and two forms:

file 1:

```
<form name="name1" action="form2.php" method="post">
     <input <? $_session['define'] = 'value1' ?> type="submit" ...>
</form>
<form name="name2" action="form2.php" method="post">
     <input <? $_session['define'] = 'value2' ?> type="submit" ...>
</form>
```

As you see i have two forms and two different submit buttons but when i press each of them, the second value (the last) set to the $_session['define'] and in the second form i always have 'value2'.

Comment: I don't understand, what is supposed to happen? In your first php snippet, you're assigning 'value1' to `session['define']`, then you just override it in the second line of php. If you're trying to case the value to be set, you have to check if the $_POST variable is set. But then, your question was terribly unclear and I don't know what was supposed to happen in the first place.

Comment: You can't set the value in the HTML. PHP is processed before the data is sent to the browser. To set these values, you need to Post the value to PHP so that PHP can enter them into the session. This can be done by clicking submit or via AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must post the data to PHP:

```
<form name="name1" action="form2.php" method="post">
     <input name='v1' value='1' type="submit" />
</form>
<form name="name2" action="form2.php" method="post">
     <input name='v2' value='2' type="submit" />
</form>
```

In form2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['value1'] = isset($_POST['v1'])?$_POST['v1']:0;
$_SESSION['value2'] = isset($_POST['v2'])?$_POST['v2']:0;
?>
```

Personally, I would make it one form and use JQuery/AJAX to POST the values.

```
<form id="selectForm" name="name1" action="form2.php" method="post">
     <input id="v1" name='v1' value='1' type="submit" />
     <input id="v2" name='v2' value='2' type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
// Requires JQuery
$("#selectForm input[id^='v']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(form2.php, { $(this).attr("name"): $(this).attr("value") }, function(){ alert("Selection Saved.) });
});
</script>
```